# how to unit test a function with multiple ifs inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, if-statement

I have this big function that I'm gonna show here, it is very simple, but somehow I cannot find how to do the unit tests for it.
I don't need the exact unit test, just a general method for ifs and even ifs cause i'm really struggling with it.
Also when I call the function in my ts (I'm using Angular.js)
this line : `this.nominativo = this.praticaDetail.operazioneDomiciliazioneDto.utente`  is the onli line that the coverage returns as covered and I dunno why cause it is identical to the followings like this  `this.variazione = this.praticaDetail.operazioneDomiciliazioneDto.dataOperazione;`

````
updateIstanza() {
    
    this.nominativo = this.praticaDetail.operazioneDomiciliazioneDto.utente 
    this.variazione = this.praticaDetail.operazioneDomiciliazioneDto.dataOperazione;
    this._bc.set('@pratica', 'Pratica ' + this.praticaDetail.numeroIstanza);
    this.accordions.splice(4, 1);
    this.richiesta();
    if (
      this.praticaDetail.funzioniDto.urlRicevuta != ''
    ) {
      this.showRicevuta = true;
    }

    if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.statoDomiciliazione == 4 || 
      this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.statoDomiciliazione == 5 || 
      this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.statoDomiciliazione == 9) {
      this.buttonDownload = true;
    }
    if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.statoDomiciliazione == 4){
      this.buttonRevoca = true;
    }
  
    if (this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.ANNULLATA) {
      this.disabledStato = true;
      this.objectAlert = {
        title: 'Istanza annullata',
        text: this.praticaDetail.operazioneDomiciliazioneDto.noteOperazione
      }
      this.visualizzaAlert = true;
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.DA_DEFINIRE){
      this.notShow = true;
      if(this.showRicevuta){
        this.buttonDownload = true;
      }
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.IN_COMPILAZIONE){
      this.annullaButton = true;
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.SOSPESA) {
      this.showDefinizioneSospInteg = true;
      this.praticaSospesa = true;
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.ATTESA_SOTTOSCRIZIONE) {
      this.showSottoscrizione = true;
      this.objectAlert = {
        title: 'Attesa Sottoscrizione',
        text: "L'integrazione è stata inserita con successo: a breve verrà generata una ricevuta che completerà il processo d'integrazione"
      }
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.IN_DEFINIZIONE) {
      this.showDefinizione = true;
      this.disabledStato = true;
    }else if(this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.ACCETTATA) {
      this.notShow = true;
      this.notShowStato = true;
      this.objectAlert = {
        title: 'Domiciliazione Bancaria accettata',
        text: ''}
      if(this.showRicevuta) {
        this.buttonDownload = true;
      }
    }else if (
      this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.IN_REVOCA) {
      if(this.praticaDetail.inAttesa){
        this.disabledStato = true;
        this.objectAlert = {
          title: 'Attesa Sottoscrizione',
          text: "La richiesta di revoca è stata inserita con successo: a breve verrà completato il processo di sottoscrizione"
        }

      } else {
        this.showAsInRevocafunction();
        this.showAnnullata = true;
        this.accordionComponent?.openAccordion(
        this.accordionComponent.CONSTANTS.ID_ACCORDIONS.DOCUMENTI
        );
        this.sottoscrizioneCompletata = true;
      }
    }else if (this.praticaDetail.statoDomiciliazioneDto.descrizione == STATI.DA_REVOCARE) {
      this.showDefinizione = true;
      this.disabledStato = true;
      this.notShowStato = true;
      if(this.praticaDetail.inAttesa){
        this.objectAlert = {
          title: 'Attesa Istituto Bancario',
          text: "L'istanza si trova in attesa dell'esito da parte dell'istituto bancario"
        }
        this.visualizzaAlert = true;
        this.showSottoscrizione = true;
      }
    }
    }
     
    }
    
    if (this.dettaglio) {
      this.accordions = [
        new AccordionAssociazioneVeicolo(),
        new AccordionDatiRichiedente(),
        new AccordionDatiRichiesta(),
        new AccordionDocumenti(),
      ];
      this.notShowStato = true;
      this.showRettifica = false;
      this.inRettifica = false;
    }
    this.eventsSubject.next({
      istanza: this.praticaDetail,
      disabledStato: this.disabledStato,
    });
  } ```
````

Comment: Building on wlf's answer, I recommend checking out Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin, Kent Beck, and Martin Fowler.  They have great resources on refactoring code into smaller functions so that it can be more easily unit tested.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup object properties so that a specific path will be tested
2. Call `updateIstanza`
3. Test against expected values

Example:

```
it('should set showRicevuta true when urlRicevuta is not empty', () => {
  const foo = new Foo();
  foo.praticaDetail.funzioniDto.urlRicevuta = 'not empty';
  foo.updateIstanza();

  expect(foo.showRicevuta).toBeTrue();
});
```

BTW having such a large function with so many control paths is not good practice.